# Get file information .bmp

Tags: encoding, metadata, bmp

I am fairly new to .bmp
I want to learn more about it. I have a .bmp file now and I wonder where I would get the headerinformation, file information etc.
Baisically, I need the written code behind the image (not open the image itself, but see what is written there - the bitmap, the header etc.).
I want to access the information you can read on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

I do not know how to open the file to get these information... I though I can read it somehow in a texteditor..

Can anyone pinpoint me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "file information" and "written code"? What is your end result, what data specifically are you looking for? Also, in which profgramming language?

Comment: @CodeCaster have a look here http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm. There the structure of the file is explained. I do not want to see the image itself, but the code which creates the image (bitmap, head etc.) I do not want to do that in a particular programming language - I though that might be something I could open in a texteditor?!

Comment: You don't have to explain the BMP file format to me, I know of it. :) If you have a hex editor, you can read all the bytes you want.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, thats the information I could not find anywhere.. All the pages displayed already the information of the file, but I did not know HOW to get them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451919/get-file-information-bmp#comment54690653_33451961):

> Assuming I want to find in the HEX Code the size of the image. How would I get that HEX Code

So, pick any BMP file and **open it in a hex editor**. From the [specification you link to](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm):

> All versions of BMP format files begin with the following 14-byte [file] header:
>
> [...]
>
> Version 4.x BMP files begin with the same 14-byte header as v2.x and v3.x BMP files. The file header is also followed by a bitmap header, which is an expanded version of the v3.x bitmap header
>
> ```
> typedef struct _Win4xBitmapHeader
> {
>     DWORD Size;            /* Size of this header in bytes */
>     LONG  Width;           /* Image width in pixels */
>     LONG  Height;          /* Image height in pixels */
>     [...]
> } WIN4XBITMAPHEADER;
> ```

So the first header is 14 bytes. The 15th-18th byte define the second header's lenght. Then follow two longs, of four bytes each, giving you the width and height of the image.

So byte 19-22 give the width, byte 23-26 give you the height - for a version 3 or 4 bitmap. Version 1 and 2 use one respectively two bytes for each dimension, so be sure to inspect the bitmap version first (by analyzing the header size).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good page that details the binary file format of .bmp images:
http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm

And of course, Microsoft itself has documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx

For viewing the raw hex data in the file, use a hex editor such as http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I am aware of that - how the file is structured etc. But how to access these information? Where can I read them when I have an actual -bmp on my computer

Comment: @Chrissl where and how those header bytes are encoded, is explained in the file format definition. You don't want to do this yourself though. There's plenty of library functions that can help you with this. It depends on the programming language or platform that you are using. If your question is _"How can I write a BMP metadata parser from scratch"_, this question is too broad.

Comment: @Chrissl You would use a programming language to write a short script to read the binary data from the file, and expose it as the numbers you're looking for.

Comment: @CodeCaster Nope, that is not my question. Assuming I want to find in the HEX Code the size of the image. How would I get that HEX Code. Or, See if there some sort of "secret message" written or change a pixels color. Where would I do that?

Comment: @DmitryBrant Thanks, thats the information I could not find anywhere.. All the pages displayed already the information of the file, but I did not know HOW to get them

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a user-friendly printout, rather than some kind of programatic access to the data, then you can use Imagemagick:

```
magick identify -verbose whatever.bmp
```

and it will print out a detailed display of the header data.